# If $f$ has an attracting fixed point, then it is not topologically transitive.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow X$ be a topological dynamical system with at
least two orbits. ($f$ is homeomorphism, the orbit $\mathcal{O}_f(x):=\{f^n(x)|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.)

Show that if $f$ has an attracting fixed point, then it is not
topologically transitive. ($X$ is locally compact, metrizable, and second countable.)

Attracting fixed point $p$ means that the fixed point $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\bar{U}$ is compact, $f(\bar{U})\subset U$, and $\cap_{n\geq 0}f^{n}(U)=\{p\}$.

Topologically transitive: there is a point $x\in X$ whose forward orbit is dense in $X$.

I don't know what to do with this condition $\cap_{n\geq 0}f^{n}(U)=\{p\}$.

Comment: Are you requiring $f$ to be a homeomorphism? Otherwise $0\mapsto 1$, $1\mapsto 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DanRust Yes, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is a homeomorphism (as otherwise counterexamples exist). Let $x$ be a point with dense orbit. Let $m$ be such that $f^m(x) \in U$, which exists by the density of the orbit of $x$. Well, then $V:=f^{-m}(U)$ also satisfies $V$ is open and contains $p$, $\bar{V}$ is compact, $f(\bar{V}) \subset V$ and $\cap_{n \geq 0} f^n(V) = \{p\}$ (check these properties). But note that $V$ contains $x$.

Can you see how this must imply that $f^n(x)$ converges to $p$? Why does this contradict the fact that $x$ supposedly has a dense orbit?

Comment: Thank you. But why does $f^n(x)$ converges to $p$ contradict the fact that $x$ supposedly has a dense orbit?

Comment: Note that if $\bar{V}=X$, then $f(\bar{V})=\bar{V}$, and so, as $f(\bar{V}) \subset V$, it means that $V=X$. Hence, $\cap_{n \geq 0}f^n(V) = \cap_{n \geq 0}f^n(X) = X \neq \{p\}$. It follows that $\bar{V} \neq X$, and so $X \setminus \bar{V}$ is non-empty and open. But then there should exist some $t \geq 0$ such that $f^t(x) \in X \setminus \bar{V}$ because $x$ has a dense forward orbit. This can't be the case because $f^t(x) \in f^t(V) \subset V \subset \bar{V}$.

Comment: Hi Dan Rust, may you please explain why these condition deduces $f^n(x)$ converges to $p$?

Comment: If $f^m(x) \in U$, then $x \in V$, hence  for all $n \geq 0$, $f^n(x) \in f^n(V)$. As $\cap_{n \geq 0} f^n(V) = \{p\}$, it means that for all $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n >N$, $V \subset B_{\epsilon}(p)$. Likewise, $f^n(x) \in B_\epsilon(p)$. Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^n(x) = p$.

Comment: @Dan Rust: Thanks so much!

Comment: @Dan Rust: Do we have the converse direction, i.e., if the sequence converges to $p$, then $\cap_{n \geq 0} f^n(V) = \{p\}$? I have asked a similar question but there is no answers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854149/definition-of-attracting-fixed-points-in-dynamical-systems-book-brin-and-stuck

Comment: If what sequence converges to $p$ and what is your $V$? You need to be more precise in your question.

Comment: @Dan Rust: I mean "Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}f^n(x) = p$ implies $\cap_{n \ge 0} f^n(U) = \{p\}$"? In my post, there is an answer that provided a counter-example.